# Exclude posts with custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I need to show a list of custom posts but exclude any that have the custom taxonomy 51, is it possible to do it with the loop below?

```
$pages = get_children(array('orderby' => 'post_date', 'post_type' => 'news', 'numberposts' => "3"));
$counter = 1;                               
foreach($pages as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    $fields = get_fields();
}
```

UPDATE:

The custom taxonomy is called opportunity and has the term id 51 in the custom taxonomy. If this helps - this is how I'm grabbing all the custom post's with the custom taxonomy opportunity:

```
$pages = get_children(array(
'orderby' => 'post_date', 
'post_type' => 'news',
'post_status' => 'future',
'numberposts' => "3",
'tax_query' => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 'news',
'field'    => 'id',
'terms'    => 51,
),
),));
```

Comment: Is "51" the name of a custom taxonomy, the ID of a term in a custom taxonomy, or the ID of a term in the Categories or Tags taxonomies? Please clarify your question and include the name of the taxonomy as well for easier reference.

Comment: @mrwweb Sorry, updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to reread the [`tax_query` documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters). If you change it to this, I think it should work:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'news',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => 51,
        operator => 'NOT IN'
    )
)
```

Depending on your setup, you may also want to specify the `include_children` argument.

Comment: Cool cheers thanks. Can't believe I didn't see that! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help. Those codex pages can all start blurring together after a while :)